# Where to store various configuration parameters in Symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

Is there best practice to store various config parameters like length of zip code, minimum length of the last name and so on?

I would like something like a php class with static functions and properties, which I can use at any place of my project.

Answer (score 1):

Your looking for parameter service.

In just released Symfony 4.1 by default: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-getting-container-parameters-as-a-service

In older Symfony with package like 
https://github.com/Symplify/PackageBuilder/blob/master/README.md#2-all-parameters-available-in-a-service
or own implementation. It's simple :)

Answer (score 1):

In the symfony best pracitces they suggest to use parameters in services.yml that  changing, if you will never change this parameter put in Entity as const or in some abstract class that you can create on by yourself.

Documentation about it:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration

Answer (score 0):

For the 3.* branch, I find that the `services.yml` file is the best place to do so. You can then inject those values into the services that need it, or even access them in your controllers with

```
$this->getParameter('param_name')
```

More info on this: see [Service Parameters](http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container.html#service-parameters)

Comment: and what about if I need a parameter not only in the service?
Or if I need more parameters? Should I inject all of them? I find this approach not so good.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers point, you can store parameters using the `parameters.yml` file.

But, for me, you are asking for limitations on entity properties. If you are using Doctrine, you can use annotations for this purpose like described in docs: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html